# Foursquare to QR Code

Tags: android, url, formatting, qr-code, foursquare

This is not too trivial, I am not looking for any code. I just want to know how to format a URL to when i scan its QR-code equivalent, it will open the Foursquare Venue ***IN APP***, NOT THE BROWSER.

This is the venues browser URL:
https://foursquare.com/v/thirsty-ernies-bar--grill/4e93838461afe52cf35aa69c
and the QR code for it:
http://qrcode.kaywa.com/img.php?s=8&d=https%3A%2F%2Ffoursquare.com%2Fv%2Fthirsty-ernies-bar--grill%2F4e93838461afe52cf35aa69c

What would I have to do for it to function like this:

http://mashable.com/2010/05/21/android-app-foursquare-checkins/

In his video, it actually opens up in the application, not just the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the link like:

foursquare://venues/yourvenueID

Where your venue ID is the row of numbers in the end of the original foursquare website venue address.

For example in the

'https://foursquare.com/v/RUSSIANCOMPANYNAMEHAPPYCODING/4d19f75f401db60ce632fea4'

'4d19f75f401db60ce632fea4' is the ID.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the android intents. Probably:

```
http://m.foursquare.com/venue/VENUE_ID
```

Try here for more info: https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client.html

Quote from that site (written by foursquare):

> Android intents are ways to link directly into the native foursquare application on Android. If you're planning to embed a link in a platform-independent medium (like a website, NFC tag, QR Code, etc.) we recommend you use Android intents for now, as they degrade nicely to the mobile website on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found out how but I was searching online for this answer but I figured it out myself.

When you scan a QR Code that has the actual URL from Foursquare check what app (Browser) the qr scanner uses to open it.

Once you know the browser go into: `Menu -> Setting -> Applications -> Manage Applications` and then find it (browser) and click "Clear Defaults"

Go back and open your qr scanner, scan the foursquare url and a menu will pop up asking which app you want to open it with.

Check use as default and hit foursquare.